# Как исправить стили под "float: left" ?

Tags: css3, html5, media-queries

Как правильно настроить стили, чтобы на малом экране блоки v1 и v2 были всегда в линию по горизонтали? Вот так, как на рисунке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, чтобы на большом экране не поломать такой расклад:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

В приведенном ниже коде на малом экране только в коротком интервале правильно работает, но в остальном, - так ломается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 428px) { /*Большой экран*/
    #aaa {float: left; width: 230px;}
    #vs1 {display : none;}
    #bbb {float: left; width: 170px;}
    #vs2 {display : block; clear: left;}
    #ccc {clear: left;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 428px) { /*Маленький экран*/
    #aaa {width: 400px;}
    #vs1 {display: block;}
    #vs2 {display: none;}
    #bbb {width: 400px;}
}
</style>
</head>  
<body>

<div id="ab" style="">

       <div id="aaa" style="height: 200px; background-color: lightgreen; opacity: 0.3;">A</div>
       <div id="vs1">
               <div id="v1" style="float: left; width: 300px; height: 40px; background-color: orange; opacity: 0.3;">v1</div>
               <div id="v2" style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 40px; background-color: khaki; opacity: 0.3;">v2</div>
       </div>
       <div id="bbb" style="height: 200px; background-color: lightblue; opacity: 0.3;">B</div>

</div>       
<div id="vs2">
               <div id="v3" style="float: left; width: 300px; height: 40px; background-color: brown; opacity: 0.3;">v3</div>
               <div id="v4" style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 40px; background-color: yellow; opacity: 0.3;">v4</div>
</div>


<div id="ccc" style="width: 400px; height: 22px; background-color: red;">C</div>

</body>
```

Comment: На flexbox решение пойдет или обязательно float:left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если говорить об отзывчивой верстке, то никаких абсолютных ширин у блоков быть не должно — это постоянно будет ломать верстку при изменении размеров окна. Конечно, если есть необходимость подстроить вывод под конкретные устройства/окна, то эти случаи стоит разбирать по отдельности.

В вашем примере ломается вывод из-за отсутствия высоты у контейнера `#vs1` на маленьких экранах. Изначально она равна `0`, так как все вложенные в него блоки с `float:left;` и поэтому блок B уезжает под них.

Более современное решение по верстке подобной конфигурации привел в сниппете с использованием `flex`. Работает на всех ширинах экранов сохраняя при этом пропорции блоков. Если нужно ограничить минимальную ширину — добавьте нужным блокам min-width и будет вам счастье ;)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#v1, #v2, #v3, #v4 {
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
#v1, #v3 {
  width: 75%;
}
#v2, #v4 {
  width: 25%;
}
#aaa, #bbb {
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
#ccc {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 428px) {
  /*Большой экран*/
  #ab {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #aaa {
    width: 57.5%;
  }
  #vs1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #bbb {
    width: 42.5%;
  }
  #vs2 {
    display: flex;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 428px) {
  /*Маленький экран*/
  #aaa {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #vs1 {
    display: flex;
  }
  #vs2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #bbb {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ab" style="">
  <div id="aaa" style="background-color: lightgreen;">A</div>
  <div id="vs1">
    <div id="v1" style="background-color: orange;">v1</div>
    <div id="v2" style="background-color: khaki;">v2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="bbb" style="background-color: lightblue;">B</div>
</div>

<div id="vs2">
  <div id="v3" style="background-color: brown;">v3</div>
  <div id="v4" style="background-color: yellow;">v4</div>
</div>

<div id="ccc" style="height: 22px; background-color: red;">C</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Помогла Ваша подсказка "из-за отсутствия высоты у контейнера #vs1". Правда, не понял почему не помогла такая правка с высотой:   <div id="vs1" style="height: 40px;">   зато вот такая с шириной 
  <div id="vs1" style="width: 400px;">   решила проблему. Thanks.

Comment: Если у вас все размеры в абсолютных значениях — то всё становится предельно просто — в инспекторе проверяете где слетает тот или иной размер и прописываете его. Хотя это странновато всё верстать с фиксированными ширинами/высотами и при этом думать об адаптивности, но вам ваша задача и среда её выполнения точнее известна.

Comment: Исходно задача сложнее. Там все width в %. Это тестовый пример, чтобы разобраться. Сейчас пытаюсь уже применить. Спасибо.